# Changing global settings for makers doesn't work in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Often I have documents where I need plots without makers. In this case I set globally a

```
\pgfplotsset{
     no markers
    }
```

However if I have some special plots in the file which require (only) markers I do it locally with the `only marks` option. The problem is that this doesn't work together with setting the marker style via `mark=`. My question is why this is the case and how to fix is.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
 no markers
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot gnuplot {x^2 + 2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[only marks,mark=star] gnuplot {x^2 + 2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]
[image]

If I comment out the line with `no markers` I get:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf):

> /pgfplots/no markers (style, no value)
>
> A key which overrides any mark value set by cycle list of option lists after \addplot.
> If this style is provided as argument to a complete axis, it is appended to every axis plot post such
> that it disables markers even for cycle lists which contain markers.

So the `mark=star` option is ignored. Nevertheless with `no markers` and `only markers` the style `/tikz/every mark` is used to draw the marks.

You can change the `every mark` style locally using `every mark/.style={mark=star}` or `mark options={mark=star}`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
 no markers
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot gnuplot {x^2 + 2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[only marks,mark options={mark=star}] gnuplot {x^2 + 2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]